# Syntax check in python in Xcode 9.0

Tags: python, c++, xcode

I am using both C++ and python on Xcode for some days. I have noticed that in python there is no syntax check before executing the program whereas in C++ there is syntax check even before executing the program.

I have attached photos with the question to make the question clear. Both the images are before running the program. Both codes have error but in C++ it is showing error but not in python.

1. [For C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr27F.png)
2. [For Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow6eQ.png)

I want to know is python like that only i.e., less checking before running of program or I am not correctly using python on Xcode.

Comment: I have asked why errors are not displayed while coding in Xcode for python. Errors you mentioned are intentionally typed to ask my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, nvm.